# mongodb group, obtain rows based on condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a table `posts` as follows:

```
+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+
| id   | title  | category  | visits  | content    |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 1    | aaa    | 1         | 44      | Text co... |
| 2    | bbb    | 1         | 63      | Text co... |
| 3    | ccc    | 2         | 42      | Text co... |
| 4    | ddd    | 2         | 65      | Text co... |
| 5    | eee    | 2         | 73      | Text co... |
| 6    | fff    | 3         | 57      | Text co... |
| 7    | ggg    | 3         | 79      | Text co... |
| 8    | hhh    | 3         | 62      | Text co... |
| 9    | iii    | 2         | 46      | Text co... |
| 10   | jjj    | 4         | 64      | Text co... |
| 11   | kkk    | 4         | 76      | Text co... |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

I am trying to obtain the **most visited posts in each category** along with their data like id, title and content.

With the below query I am able to obtain an entry for each category

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
        "_id": "$category", 
        "count": {"$sum": 1},
        "max-visits": { $max: "$visits" }
    }}
]);
```

I am able to obtain the category along with maximum of visitors of that category and the no of posts in it. But I also **require id, title and content of the post that has maximum visits.**

Expected output:

```
    +------+--------+----------------+---------+------------+
    | id   | title  | category(_id)  | visits  | content    |
    +------+--------+----------------+---------+------------+
    | 1    | bbb    | 1              | 63      | Text co... |
    | 2    | eee    | 2              | 73      | Text co... |
    | 3    | ggg    | 3              | 79      | Text co... |
    | 4    | kkk    | 4              | 76      | Text co... |
    +------+--------+----------------+---------+------------+
```

Actual output:

```
    +-----------------+--------+-------------+
    | category(_id)   | count  | max-visits  |
    +-----------------+--------+-------------+
    | 1               | 2      | 63          |
    | 2               | 4      | 73          |
    | 3               | 3      | 79          |
    | 4               | 2      | 76          |
    +-----------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you update your post to show the aggregate query you have attempted thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `$sort` before `$group` then you can easily get [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) document's fields.

```
db.posts.aggregate([
{"$sort": { category: 1, visits: -1 }},
{"$group": {
    "_id": "$category", 
    "count": {"$sum": 1},
    "max-visits": { $max: "$visits" },
    "doc_id": { $first: "$_id" },
    "title": { $first: "$title" },
    "content": { $first: "$content" }
}}
]);
```

Comment: it should be `$last`, not `$first`